# Tape is required when a tensor loss is passed

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have the following loss:

```
loss = loss(y_train_left_noc[:,:,0], soft_argmin).tolist()
```

where type(loss) is <class 'float'>

However, upon using this loss in the optimizer like so:

```
train = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam().minimize(loss, [k1, k2, k3])
```

where k1, k2 and k3 are convolution kernels, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 277, in <module>
    k3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 385, in minimize
    loss, var_list=var_list, grad_loss=grad_loss, tape=tape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 440, in _compute_gradients
    raise ValueError("`tape` is required when a `Tensor` loss is passed.")
ValueError: `tape` is required when a `Tensor` loss is passed.
```

If the loss is of type float, then why does Tensorflow say that a `Tensor` loss is passed?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are exactly trying to do and also share the complete reproducible code so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering the solution from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42447#issuecomment-675778979) by @nikitamaia, for the benefit of the community.

The error message you're seeing is [here in the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/43cfb92ac5e2348718155905245194723f674697/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L499):

```
if not callable(loss) and tape is None:
    raise ValueError("`tape` is required when a `Tensor` loss is passed.")
```

This error message seems only to be in **tf-nightly**, and if you run the code in **TF 2.3** you'll notice a slightly different error message `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable` which is perhaps a more clear message. Either way, since you're passing a scalar loss value, and not a callable, an error is expected. If you want to use a scalar loss value and not pass the callable, then you should use **GradientTape**, as noted in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Example code.

If loss is a tensor the following need to be added:

```
with tf.control_dependencies(gen_updates):
  d_train_opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=LR_D, 
    beta_1=BETA1
  ).minimize(
      d_loss, 
      var_list=d_vars
    )
```

```
with tf.control_dependencies(gen_updates):
  d_train_opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=LR_D, 
    beta_1=BETA1
  ).minimize(
      d_loss, 
      var_list=d_vars,
      tape=tf.GradientTape(persistent=False)
    )
```